# Change .pdf-file-icon under Total Commander

Tags: file-management, icon-packs

I have recently installed the Dropbox app and it overwrote the standard pdf-file-icon my file manager was displaying. i don't like the dropbox-pdf-icon and would like to have the previous one back.

> Is this possible w/o uninstalling the Dropbox app?

p.s. I have a rooted device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total Commander (TC will show the first returned icon for that type. It seems.to be impossible to reorder them by hand. TC calls packageManager.queryIntentActivities to find out which apps are associated with a certain file type. If none of them is marked as a default, TC uses the first one in the mentioned list. But there is no clue (yet) in which order these are returned by Android.

You may also choose your own:

1. Go to: Main menu - Configure - Internal associations
2. Add new extension: .pdf
3. Choose an icon via button in the lower left